# "Dimensions" not shown under "Transform" panel

Tags: dimensions

I'm just trying to edit the dimensions of a cube, and I've hit 'N' to open the properties panel, but there's no "Dimensions" that I can edit under this tab, just "Median", "Vertices Data", and "Edges Data".  Does anyone know how to get blender to show me the dimensions table?

Thanks

Comment: are you in edit mode or object mode? Because the object dimensions will only show up in object mode.

Answer (score 2):

Dimensions do not show in "Edit mode" only in "Object mode"